# How to match arrays and show the one that are NOT in the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a two array with with different values. I'd like to match the arrays and spearate the values that is not match. It's my current script:

```
var array_must_exist = ['4','5'];
var array_to_compare = [{"NO": "1"},{"NO": "2"},{"NO": "5"},{"NO": "7"}];

$.each(array_to_compare, function(i, result){   

   var arr = jQuery.grep(array_must_exist, function(value) {

                return value != result.NO;
             });

    alert(arr);
});
```

When `array_must_exist` is in `array_to_compare` the `arr` returns `5` and `4`. How to alert the one is not in the array?

if `array_to_compare = [{"NO": "1"},{"NO": "4"}];` the alert is `5 is missing`
if `array_to_compare = [{"NO": "5"},{"NO": "6"},{"NO": "3"}];` the alert is `4 is missing`
if `array_to_compare = [{"NO": "4"},{"NO": "5"},{"NO": "6"},{"NO": "7"}];` the alert is `Nothing is missing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `.filter()` the `array_must_exist` array down to ones where `.some()` is not able to locate a match in `array_to_compare`.

```js
var array_must_exist = ['4','5'];
var array_to_compare = [{"NO": "1"},{"NO": "2"},{"NO": "5"},{"NO": "7"}];


var missing = array_must_exist.filter(n =>   // `n` is the current number.
  !array_to_compare.some(obj => obj.NO == n) // See if `n` is in any object.
);


console.log("missing:", missing.length ? missing : "None")
```

So for each item in `array_must_exist`, if "not some" (or in other words "none") are found in `array_to_compare`, that value will be included in the result. If the result is empty, then all were found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions `reduce` and `findIndex` to extract the missing values.

```js
function compare(array_must_exist, array_to_compare) {
  return array_must_exist.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (array_to_compare.findIndex((a) => a.NO === c) === -1) a.push(c);
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log('Missing:', compare(['4','5'], [{"NO": "1"},{"NO": "2"},{"NO": "5"},{"NO": "7"}]).join());
console.log('Missing:', compare(['4','5'], [{"NO": "4"}]).join());
console.log('Missing:', compare(['4','5'], [{"NO": "4"}, {"NO": "5"}]).join());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```